# how can i install the mate login screen on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: unity, login-screen, mate

I just installed mate's desktop on ubuntu focal fossa 20.04. I already have ubuntu unity downloaded on my pc. so the login screen is unity's login screen. how do I change it to mate's login screen via a terminal command? i'm asking because when i installed mate the login screen didn't change.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu MATE, Ubuntu Unity or just the plain and the original ubuntu?

Comment: i have both installed. currently im using unity right now. but i can easily switch to mate if i want to via the unity login screen.

Comment: No like i'm not asking what Desktop you are using... i am asking what flavor of ubuntu you are running?

Comment: i am not sure what that means but to be clear i am on ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa and i have install unity desktop environment and mate desktop environment. i have not downloaded the ubuntu 20.04 unity desktop. i have downloaded ubuntu's normal desktop, and installed unity on it through the terminal command sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop and i have installed mate through the terminal command sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop. is that clear enough?

Comment: Okay.... You have the original version of ubuntu installed.

Comment: yes, i do, too.

Comment: so? is that all?...

Comment: Try removing gdm. unity by default uses lightdm, which MATE also uses, so you should be good to go.

Comment: that's exactly my problem. because they both are under lightdm, i cant pick between the unity's lightdm and the mate's lightdm, as my only options are gdm and lightdm.

Comment: The only way out of this is to switch to [Ubuntu MATE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSapM.jpg) and install Unity using the commands you mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Edit this file: /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf

```
sudo vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

on [greeter] section add your image path:

```
[greeter]
background=/usr/share/backgrounds/mate/nature/Dune.jpg
```

Logout and done.